# Is Tier 2 dependent possible for recent civil partnership? (UK Visa)

Tags: working-visas, immigration, uk-visa, dependent-visa

I have been offered a job in London to work for an A-rated sponsor. The company has attorneys that made applications for a Skilled Worker (my case) and Skilled Worker dependent (my partner's case).

We have signed a Civil Partnership document in Nov 24th 2022 (last month), stating that we have been in a Civil Partnership since May 12th, 2021.

However, since the Civil Partnership deed was recently signed, would it have a negative impact in her Skilled Worker dependent visa application?

In her application, we have submited only photos of our relationship. No shared bills, etc. since I currently pay everything (she is ending her college and currently works as an intern for a company).

Comment: Ask the company's attorneys who made the visa application on your behalf.

Comment: You say that you have signed a 'Civil Partnership' document. Do you mean that you have actually reigstered a recognized civil partnership by the laws of your home country? Would you mind stating which country that is?

Comment: Yes, and it is recognized by the UK. My home country is Brazil.